# How can we translate the word "foudre" in english, is there an equivalent ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

"Foudre" is "lightning"+" thunder" but when I look for the translation of "foudre" I find only "lightning"

Someone has an idea ? 
Thank you
 (I'm a native french speaker from Belgium)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the English language. You can ask it on [english.se] or [ell.se], but make clear what kind of word you are looking for and for what reasons.

Comment: I see. Sorry I was not sure where to go since it's the translation of a french word but thanks for the redirection.

Comment: "Foudre/lightning" is composed of "Eclair/lightning strike (/flash)" (flash of light) and "Tonnerre/thunder" (sound) that occur during a storm called "Orage/thunderstorm". Hope this helps even though the question is put on hold.

Comment: This is not about English, either. It's about translation from French to English.

Comment: @refreshfr thanks, that is what I found finally but I thought that lightning is "éclair" too ? Maybe it's only a false usage though.

Comment: @Jirei What I've said in my comment is the correct usage of words, but in reality, "éclair/foudre" are almost interchangeable ("éclair" is often used instead of the correct word "foudre", rarely the other way around). A lot of (french) people don't know the difference/nuance, so both are "considered correct" and will be correctly understood.

Comment: I see, thank you :)